# Multiplatform application to be executed from USB key

Tags: usb, multiplatform

A client asked me to realize an application that must be executed from a USB key in Mac or Windows. It must be run without installation, the user has to insert the USB key and the program should run.
I'm thinking to use Electron by copying .exe for Win and .app for Mac and all the files needed for the runtime on the USB key, but have never tried that.
Has anyone tried it or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify a little more which kind of application you need.
For example, assuming a browser is installed on every Windows PC and MacOS and internet connection is available maybe you can simply put a "welcome.html" file in the pendrive which is the entry point for a web based program which is the best way to be device independent but could not be suitable for every kind of application request.

Regarding USB portable like application I did something on windows in the past, working with Sybase PowerBuilder 7 you can make a program exe not using COM OLE classes and fancy framework, only the core components. In that case you do not need to install anything, just copy all the required dll , which can be easily spot by using Procmon / procexp tools in the same folder where the exe is located. 
Basically the same concept of many C++ based portable open source programs that you can find on sourceforge.

Comment: I need to create a web application that can generate PDFs on the fly. I would use ReactJS, in this case i think to include react files in html script tag and i cannot use npm or yarn because i'm not sure that the user has them installed.